# How can I lock a user profile field after registration?

Tags: 7, users

I have a custom field on my user's profiles; I would like it is filled out at registration, but then not changed on post-registration.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you use the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module?  You could set permissions on the field so that authenticated users (or any other user role if you're using any) cannot edit this specific field, but anonymous (registering) users can.